# RHEL6 undo virtual client rhel6

Tags: linux, redhat, kvm-virtualization

I am running rhel6 on my laptop. I was playing with the Open Client Go Virtual and accidently installed a KVM image of RHEL6. It runs the full virtual machine. I want to unregister, delete and reclaim my disk space. How can I do this?

I keep getting this error:

```
$ sudo virsh vol-list --pool default
Name                 Path                                    
-----------------------------------------
Virtual_Client_RHEL_6-KVM.qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images/Virtual_Client_RHEL_6-KVM.qcow2
Virtual_Client_RHEL_6-KVM.qcow2.type /var/lib/libvirt/images/Virtual_Client_RHEL_6-KVM.qcow2.type

$ sudo virsh vol-delete --pool default Virtual_Client_RHEL_6-KVM.img
error: failed to get vol 'Virtual_Client_RHEL_6-KVM.img'
error: Storage volume not found: no storage vol with matching path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, delete your virtual machine with the command
 `virsh undefine Virtual_Client_RHEL_6-KVM`

Then, remove the disk file using 
`virsh vol-delete /var/lib/libvirt/images/Virtual_Client_RHEL_6-KVM.qcow2`

If you have problem with text-only virsh, please install the `virt-manager` package to use a graphical client.